# How to authenticate users from another domain in an ASP.NET SaaS application?

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, saas

We have an ASP.NET web application that we offer as a Service (it's hosted and it's accessible on the Web). We use Forms Authentication and our users have to enter a username/password to connect to our application. Some of our customers ask that we support single sign-on by authenticating users with their own Active Directory.

Our application has a different URL for each customer

```
www.ourapp.com/client1/
www.ourapp.com/client2/
www.ourapp.com/client3/
```

and each URL has its own web.config file (where asp.net settings can be specified and can vary for each customer).

- What do I have to change in my ASP.NET application to support that?
- What do I have to change on my Windows server configuration?
- What will the customer have to do on his side to enable that?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360) In short, you configure an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to verify each username/password with the customer's AD. The customer must create an AD account for you that is allowed to perform the verification - which may be a problem with some customers. What's more, your code will handle the actual username/password used by users in their internal network, which can be an even bigger problem with customers.

A more secure solution is to use federation (using [ADFS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772128(WS.10).aspx)) or Claims Authentication using [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx). In this case you "only" have to set trust relations between your domain and theirs.

Comment: After some reading, ADFS 2.0 (combined with WIF) seems to be the way to go. Thanks for the links...